# gitlab docker runner mvn: command not found

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to build **ci/cd** withing GitLab runner docker image

```
build:
  script:
    - mvn install
```

But I face below error

```
 $ mvn install
 bash: line 85: mvn: command not found
```

Comment: What image did you specify in your GitLab CI config to be used for the builder? You will need one which contains maven, e.g. the official https://hub.docker.com/_/maven

Comment: The image used is image: maven:latest

Comment: Can you paste your .gitlab-ci.yaml file here?